# Ray add multiple code search path to cluster

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ray

My code is working in **JupyterNotebook** (imported all the libraries, packages, used sys.path.append to add folders to work with / bigger project. The problems keep on coming when I map my custom function to remote workers, I get **ModuleNotFoundError**.

```
ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True)

@ray.remote
def compute_pos(pos, img):
    img_p = lib_x.Image.FromString(img)
    img_c = lib_x.Image()
    img_c.CopyFrom(img_p)
    img_pos = pos(img_c)
    return img, img_pos.SerializeToString()


pos_X = make_predictor(config_dict)

def parmap(f, list_x, pos):
    return [f.remote(pos, x) for x in list_x]

result_ids = parmap(compute_pos, serialized_imgs, pos_X)

results = ray.get(result_ids)
```

I also tried out setting runtime_env params at ray.init(), but it did not help:

```
rntm_env = {"working_dir": sys.path, "py_modules": [lib_x, make_predictor]}
ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True, runtime_env=rntm_env)
```

How could I pass all pythonpath & imported dependencies from my notebook to ray?
I also have to mention that I am in search of a solution, without using any Conda related.

Comment: Can you specify what `lib_x` is in `"py_modules": [lib_x, make_predictor]`? It should automatically be inserted into your python path.

Comment: lib_x is a custom module, it is used by compute_pos.

Comment: BTW I made some progress since yesterday: after giving pymodules the right paths, I get the following error message (cluster is initialised, packages are pushed): 
`TypeError: can't pickle google.protobuf.pyext._message.MessageDescriptor objects

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
ypeError: Could not serialize the argument <posX.predictor.PosPredictor object at 0x7f93c8ff2090> for a task or actor __main__.compute_position. Check https://docs.ray.io/en/master/serialization.html#troubleshooting for more information.`